# Why am I getting extra stuff when looping through methods?

Tags: java, reflection

Okay not sure what is going on.  I am using Java Reflection and iterating and inspecting methods of a particular class.  Below is the following code I am using:

```
public void test(){

    Class useCases = Car.class;

    Method[] methods = useCases.getMethods();
    Integer[] numbers = {2, 5};
    String[] numberStrings = {"2", "5"};
    for(int i=0; i<methods.length; i++){
        try {
            System.out.print(methods[i].getName());
            Method method = useCases.getMethod(methods[i].getName(), new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class});
            Object returnV = method.invoke(new Car(), numberStrings[i], numbers[i]);
            System.out.print(returnV.toString() + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Car Class:

```
public String getNumber(String number, Integer times){
    return times == 2 ? number : null;
}

public String getNumber1(String number, Integer times){
    return times == 5 ? number : null;
}
```

It loops through fine printing out the first two methods and the return value fine, but then it continues and prints out a wait() and not sure why and I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sample.Car.wait(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Integer)

Any help as to why the loop does not end with just printing and returning the values for the only two methods in that Car class.

Comment: Why are you doing `Method method = useCases.getMethod(methods[i].getName(), new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class});` just to get back `methods[i]`?

Comment: What I provided is not something I am using in production.  I am merely practicing since I just starting using this method.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck with it - reflection is really cool.

Comment: Yeah I can see some really cool examples that I can apply to what I am doing.  Now I am trying to figure out how when I iterate through these methods that have different parameters.  I could have two methods Method1(String value) and the other be Method2(String value, Integer value2). But I'd like to go and figure that out and if I have issues then I'll ask here :)  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getMethods` returns all public methods available for class, including the ones inherited like `wait()` `toString()` which as you see don't accept `(String, Integer)` arguments, which is why

```
useCases.getMethod(methods[i].getName(), new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class});
```

is not able to find `wait(String, Integer)`.

To get only methods declared in `Car` class use `getDeclaredMethods` instead.

BTW: instead of

```
System.out.print(returnV.toString() + "\n");
```

which will throw `NullPointerException` on `returnV.toString()` if `returnV` will be `null` use

```
System.out.println(returnV); // also you don't need to explicitly add `\n`,
                             // use println will add used by current OS line 
                             // separator for you automatically
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah this is just practice I am not using this for anything real, at least not what I provided.  But that is a point I will remember.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Every Class is implicitly extending Object, so you get all methods containing in Object too.